# IndexPath.row is not unique for Static Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath, nsindexpath

I have a TableViewController with static cells and section headers. I tried to call `indexPath.row` however, they are not unique.. For example

```
TableView:
- Header 1
  - Cell1  indexPath = 0
- Header 2
  - Cell2  indexPath = 0
  - Cell3  indexPath = 1
  - Cell4  indexPath = 2
```

What is the proper way of getting unique identifiers for rows?

---

Because using this make 2 cells have the same indexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
   print(indexPath.row)

   if indexPath.row != 0 {
     return indexPath
   }

   return nil
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be ignoring `indexPath.section`. The combination of section and row uniquely define the index path. A row is unique within its section.

Answer (score 2):

`NSIndexPath` consist of `row` and `section`, combination of `section` and `row` is unique
Cell1 in your case has `indexPath.section == 0` and `indexPath.row == 0`
Cell2 has `indexPath.section == 1` and `indexPath.row == 0`

Comment: So for example for Cell2, should I use `if indexPath.section == 1 && if indexPath.section == 0 { }`?

Comment: FYI - the `section` and `row` of `NSIndexPath` is actually an extension provided by `UITableView`. `UICollectionView` adds `section` and `item`. The original `NSIndexPath` doesn't have such properties. It just has a set of indexes.

Comment: @senty Yes, for Cell2 it would be section 1, row 0.